# How to create mongo user on existing db with correct role?

Tags: mongodb, centos

I have restored a database on mongo and when I try to add user for this database. It is giving error:

```
use abcdb_1;
switched to db abcdb_1
> db.createUser( { user: "adminxx", pwd: "123123", roles: [ "userAdminAnyDatabase" ] } );
2018-02-27T07:25:05.989+0500 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't add user: No role named userAdminAnyDatabase@abcdb_1:
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
DB.prototype.createUser@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1267:15
@(shell):1:1
```

What is wrong in it? How can I add admin user in this db so I access it in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to run the command:

```
show role;
```

then choose a role from list and create user again with that role with same command.

Comment: I have faced the same issue before. It is correct solution.